# meta_value and meta_key filtering returning no posts

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, meta-value

this might sound like a very stupid question, and I am almost ashamed to put it here... however, after using the code straight from wp codex, and trying a couple of other variations from googling around, i simply have NO IDEA why this is not working!

here's what i am using for the wp query on the index.php

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('photographs', 'published_works'),
    'meta_key' => 'place',
    'meta_value' => 'usa',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);
```

i set up a custom taxonomy called 'place', and 'usa' is one of the terms. i can get to the archive page easily, but if i want to filter it out in the index page, it simply shows no posts at all.

so, i am assuming that the mistake is probably elsewhere, since the code above is taken straight from codex. any ideas of what i might be doing wrong???

much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and [meta data (Custom Fields)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) are two different things. If you want to filter on a taxonomy term, you want a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), not a meta query.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think you want to use [Taxonomy Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) (you have to set up a custom taxonomy, so it has nothing to do with custom fields) and not a Meta/Custom Field Query.

Comment: Maybe you want to elaborate _why_ this helps and show a brief example. So far it should be a comment.